# inserting multiple products at a time in database using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to insert product name,product price,product image,multiple images for one product URL,in MySQL database using php code-igniter .i m very new to php and codeigniter.at one time i want to insert least 600 products?how to do it?i can upload products through csv also but no idea how to do it

Comment: Have you do anything?

Comment: it would help if you share your database schema

Comment: Read http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-beginner-guide/ and http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `insert_batch()` to insert multiple rows in codeigniter

First populate the array for products like this

```
$data[0]['name'] = "Name";
$data[0]['price'] = "Price";
...

$data[1]['name'] = "Name";
$data[1]['price'] = "Price";
...

$data[2]['name'] = "Name";
$data[2]['price'] = "Price";
...

$this->db->insert_batch("table_name",$data);
```

Comment: do i need to write anything in controller and view?